# makefile into debian package, copy files and directories recursively

Tags: deb, dpkg, software-packaging

I realized that with `debian/rules`

```
override_dh_auto_install:
       dh_auto_install -- prefix=/usr
```

it's impossible to get a file copied into the directory structure of the debian package with the `cp` command, but with `install` yes. So I understood, or interpreted that only the `install` command is interpreted by the `dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc -ui -i` command to copy temporarilly the files into the .deb file before installing them during any `dpkg -i` process.

The problem is that when I want to copy many files and an entire directory structure, I'm unable to do it as mentionned in various places on the web with tricks like `find` command for ex.

So the problems I have now is how from a Makefile do I specify that I want that to be converted into real world of debian package??!!!

```
cp -r some/src/dir/from/current_dir /to/opt/myCompany/for/example/bin
ln -s /to/opt/myCompany/for/example/bin/ /usr/local/bin
```

Both are misinterpreted by the `dpkg-buildpackage`